# Date Compare between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following results where I have added an extra column for ExpectedResult.

I'm not sure how to go about getting this to work where the DateFrom value should be compared to the next DateFrom value until the final row within that Category where it should compare to the DateTo value. DateTo could also be NULL, where it should compare to getdate() in that case.

Anyone have any ideas on how this could be achieved?

[image]

For Category 1, The comparison is done from 2019-03-01 to 2019-03-08, then from 2019-03-08 to 2019-03-11 and the finally from 2019-03-11 to 2019-03-14 and then resets for the next category.

**Sample Data:**

```
Create Table #TestData
(
    ID int,
    Category int,
    DateFrom datetime,
    DateTo datetime NULL,
    ExpectedResult int
)

insert into #TestData
(
    ID,
    Category,
    DateFrom,
    DateTo,
    ExpectedResult
)
select
    1,
    1,
    '01 Mar 2019',
    '06 Mar 2019',
    7
union all
select
    2,
    1,
    '08 Mar 2019',
    '09 Mar 2019',
    3
union all
select
    3,
    1,
    '11 Mar 2019',
    '14 Mar 2019',
    3
union all
select
    1,
    2,
    '04 Mar 2019',
    '07 Mar 2019',
    4
union all
select
    2,
    2,
    '08 Mar 2019',
    '15 Mar 2019',
    10
union all
select
    3,
    2,
    '18 Mar 2019',
    '24 Mar 2019',
    6

select  * from #TestData

drop table #TestData
```

Comment: I can't see how you are generating your expected result from the data in the table.

Comment: Sorry if that wasn't detailed enough @Nick, have updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you mainly search for the `lead()` window function. And for `datediff()` to get the difference in days and `coalesce()` to replace `NULL`s.

```
SELECT id,
       category,
       datefrom,
       dateto,
       expectedresult,
       datediff(day,
                datefrom,
                lead(datefrom,
                     1,
                     coalesce(dateto,
                              getdate())) OVER (PARTITION BY category
                                                ORDER BY datefrom)) calculatedexpectedresult
       FROM #testdata;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a4626e7e32b8836b44c9704a39ef85e3)